# What's the Azure CLI equivalent of "aws s3 cp ./index.html s3://mybucket"

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-storage, azure-cli

I want to upload a static html file to the $web folder on an Azure storage account. How do I do this from the Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following steps (in Bash on WSL):

(1.) run

```
az storage account show-connection-string -n MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g MY_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --query connectionString -o tsv
```

to obtain a Storage connection string, which will look something like:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=jamesexampleaccountname;AccountKey=ABc1/D1EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/ABCDEFGHIJK/LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPq==
```

(2.) run

```
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=jamesexampleaccountname;AccountKey=ABc1/D1EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/ABCDEFGHIJK/LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPq=="
```

NOTE: the Storage connection string has to be enclosed in quotes for this to work.

(3.) finally, to upload the file run:

```
az storage blob upload -c '$web' -f "index.html" -n "index.html"
```

NOTE: $web must be enclosed in **SINGLE** quotes for this to work.